# Photon or Smartfox for a quiz game with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, photon, smartfoxserver

I'm starting a new project and it's a quiz, which be written with `Unity`.

Right now, i have to make a choice between `Smartfox` and `Photon`. One of the requirements is to contain a database with questions and answers for the quiz.
I ask to share experience, and help to make the right decision)).

Which of the two tools would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go for smartfoxserver, as it is the leading multiplayer server and a very sophisticated server side java api as well. You can write your algorithms and turn based logic on server that way it will be secure, robust and manageable and will be called through extensions calls from client side.

You can find many examples on their [website](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/ExamplesUnity/introduction), with server side [extensions](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/DevelopmentBasics/writing-extensions) introduction and details as well. And a very good helping community forum.

For questions and answers that will be stored in a database. One of the best thing with smartfoxserver is, it can connect to database and than it will be a local access to database and you can execute queries and call stored procedures directly from server side API and manipulate results in just next line. Make it more secure and flexible.

Also your questions will be coming from server directly which is connected to your database. No need to handle API calls on client side.

It is a perfect scenario for multiplayer quiz game.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

I would use photon, as I have more experience with it. It comes with a good example on how to make turn based games, and is relatively easy to use. It is essentially good for everything, so you can't go wrong.